# Ruby on Rails Events Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am relatively new to Ruby on Rails. I have built few sample apps but now I want to build a real world app like an events website which gives information on forthcoming events, event galleries, etc. Can some one give more ideas on this or something already built on github to learn using it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the types of question you are asking, it seems to me that you are not very experience in Rails. Therefore, I recommend you to complete Michael Hartl's tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book. Although it won't teach how to make galleries and such, it will teach you the fundamentals that you need for your app. For instance, in your case you will understand how to create an Event model with information in a database that you can then show. After that, you can go ahead and check out things like spud_photos( https://github.com/gregawoods/spud_photos) which is a gem that allows you to create image galleries.

Good luck